# linux command: show content of all files

Tags: linux, find, ls, xargs

I tried the two following cmd to show content of all files under current directory. I want to know why one works, the other does not.

```sh
ls | xargs cat # does not work, No such file or directory

find . | xargs cat # works
```

`cat` is just an example, it can be any cmd which takes a file name as its parameter.

---------------------------------Update---------------------------------

Here are some observation from my PC.

```
$ echo 1 > test1.txt
$ echo 2 > test2.txt
$ echo 3 > test3.txt

$ ls
test1.txt  test2.txt  test3.txt

$ ls *.txt | xargs cat
cat: test1.txt: No such file or directory
cat: test2.txt: No such file or directory
cat: test3.txt: No such file or directory

$ find .  -name '*.txt' | xargs cat
2
1
3
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the behaviour you are reporting.  I would guess it is a feature of the filenames that you are using.  If I use filenames with spaces in (for instance) then I can get `ls | xargs cat` to not work but the find command you give does not work either!  So you need to do a bit more work figuring out under what conditions this problem occurs

Comment: @Vorsprung thanks for your reply. I added `update` in my original post containing results observed from my pc.  Please check it out.

Comment: is ls aliased to anything? The format you get indicates not, but maybe try with \ls to be sure...

Comment: @timofiend you are right...  it's a aliais issue. `type ls` shows `ls is aliased to 'command ls --color'`. `\ls` works. Thank you. =)

Answer (score 0):

For others that might see this, we found the issue in the comments. Hao's problem was that ls was an alias, causing issues piping xargs to cat.

With 'type ls', they saw it was aliased, and using '\ls' to remove the alias solved the problem.